# how to pass attribute by value to backend bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, myfaces, omnifaces

if "f:attribute" is a simple string and pass like:
<f:attribute name="selectedUserEmail" value="TADA" />
than all works fine, TADA is passed correctly.
But when its passed like #{manageUserView.selectedUser.email} - than its null.

```
<ui:composition ...
    <ui:define name="metadata">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewAction action="#{manageUserView.init}" />
        </f:metadata>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">

<!-- indentations are broken on purpose so code will fit the page -->
<h:form id="editUserForm">
    <p:accordionPanel> ...
        <p:tab>
            <div class="field grid">
                <p:outputLabel for="emailInput" value="Email" class="col-12 mb-2 md:col-2 md:mb-0"/>
                <div class="col">
                    <p:inputText id="emailInput" 
                        value="#{manageUserView.selectedUser.email}"
                        maxlength="100"
                        required="true"
                        requiredMessage="Please enter value"
                        validator="#{emailValidator.validate}"/>
                    <p:message for="emailInput"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="field grid">
                <p:outputLabel for="pwd1" value="Password" class="col-12 mb-2 md:col-2 md:mb-0"/>
                <div class="col">
                    <p:password id="pwd1" 
                        value="#{manageUserView.selectedUser.password}"
                        validator="#{passwordValidator.validate}"
                        required="true" 
                        requiredMessage="Please enter value">
                            <f:attribute name="selectedUserEmail" value="#{manageUserView.selectedUser.email}" />
                    </p:password>
                    <p:message for="pwd1"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        ...

            <p:commandButton id="saveButton"
                action="#{manageUserView.save()}"/>
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel> 
</h:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
```

```
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;
@Component("manageUserView")
@ViewScoped
public class ManageUserView implements Serializable {

    ...
    @Getter @Setter private User selectedUser;

    public void init() {
        selectedUser = new User();
    }

    public void save() {
        // at this point selectedUser is not null, 
        // and values inserted by user, like email, have correct inserted values. 
        // All good.
    }
}
```

```
import jakarta.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent;
import jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext;
import jakarta.faces.validator.Validator;
import jakarta.faces.validator.ValidatorException;
... 
@Service("passwordValidator")
public class PasswordValidatorImpl implements PasswordValidator, Validator<Object>, Serializable {

    ...
    
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException
    {
        String selectedUserEmail = (String)component.getAttributes().get("selectedUserEmail");
        
        //selectedUserEmail always null here, why? thanks!
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class FacesExceptionFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean<FacesExceptionFilter> filterRegisBean()
    {
        final FilterRegistrationBean<FacesExceptionFilter> filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();

        filterRegBean.setFilter(new FacesExceptionFilter());
        filterRegBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        filterRegBean.setEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
        return filterRegBean;
    }

    @Bean
    ErrorPageRegistrar errorPageRegistrar()
    {
        return new ErrorPageRegistrar() {
            @Override
            public void registerErrorPages(final ErrorPageRegistry registry) {
                registry.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/page1"));
                registry.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/bla-page2"));
                registry.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, "... and so on"));
                registry.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "... and so on"));
                registry.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "... and so on"));
            }
        };
    }
}

public class FacesExceptionHandlerFactory extends ExceptionHandlerFactory {

    public FacesExceptionHandlerFactory(final ExceptionHandlerFactory parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
        final ExceptionHandler result = getWrapped().getExceptionHandler();
        return new FacesExceptionHandler(result);
    }

}


import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
@ViewScoped
public class ManageUserView implements Serializable {...}
```

```
import jakarta.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import jakarta.faces.event.PhaseId;
import jakarta.faces.event.PhaseListener;

@Service
public class ViewLifeCycleListener implements PhaseListener {
    
    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getPhaseId().getOrdinal() == 1) 
        {
            log.debug("PhaseEvent #1 called");
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) 
    {
        // RENDER_RESPONSE - last phase of the JSF lifecycle
        if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) 
        {
            log.debug("Finished rendering view for last phase: {}",event.getPhaseId());
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() 
    {
        return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
    }
    
    private Optional<Long> getPhaseTimeFromMap(String username) 
    {
        return Optional.ofNullable(userPhaseTimeMap.get(username));
    }   
}
```

PrimeFaces v12.x, MyFaces(latest), Faces(JSF) v4.x, Omnifaces v4.x

Highly appreciate the help
--vs

Comment: In `manageUserView.selectedUser.email` most likely the `selectedUser` is NULL this the email is `null`.

Comment: sorry, I was have to clarify that selectedUser I'm generating in the code manually with new, so its not null, but rather value of email, that is inserted by user in the @form, is transferred to back end always as null. I've edited the original question.

Comment: This can happen when `#{manageUserView}` is newly created between the actions. Put a breakpoint or logger in its `@PostConstruct` to assert that. Btw in JSF/Facelets it's the norm to use `#{}` expressions and surely not JSP-minded `${}` expressions. This will avoid a lot of confusion by yourself and future maintainers of your code and of course people trying to answer your question here.

Comment: thank you, replaced all ${} with #{}. Not quite sure if I understood the @PostConstruct comment correctly: to put it in the manageUserView? than selectedUSer is always null, cause its not created. I've again modified/added some more code to original question (not sure how much will be relevant if I put it all at once). Thanks!

Comment: You're using Spring to manage beans instead of standard CDI or JSF. Spring by default doesn't at all support JSF native bean scopes. How exactly did you configure Spring to recognize the OmniFaces `@ViewScoped` annotation? There are several ways, good and wrong. How exactly have you asserted that the bean is really in the view scope? Normally you'd just put a debug breakpoint or a temporary logger line in bean methods annotated with `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` and observe the behavior while opening the page, submitting the page and closing/navigating away.

Comment: @BalusC "How exactly did you configure Spring to recognize the OmniFaces ViewScoped annotation?" - I did not. I thought JoinFaces doing its magic. How is it done properly? Thanks

Comment: [JoinFaces only recognizes `jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped`](https://docs.joinfaces.org/current/reference/#_jsf_and_cdi_scope_annotations_support). Try it instead. If it works then you've found the cause. If you want to continue using `org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped` including unload facility then you may find [this article](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2023/11/using-omnifaces-cdi-viewscoped-with.html) useful.

Comment: Thanks! Now used jakarta \@ViewScoped and finally \@PostConstruct started to work on page create! And to accomplish \@PreDestroy will later switch to Omnifaces with the help of your article.